# Flattening any xml record in java

Tags: java, xml

So basically, I am having problem turning my head around this one.

Basically, I can have any type of xml.. and I have to parse it.

I am able to parse it succesfully for "flat" xml.
So for example:

```
<emp>
<id>1</id>
<name>foo</name>
<age>22</age>
</emp>
```

My simple parser works fine for this (note that schema is variable.. any flat xml (no hardcoding)..

But it fails for nested xml stuff
So

```
<emplist>
<emp>
   <manager>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>foo</name>
   </manager>
</emp>
<emp>
   <clerk>
   <cid>1</cid>
   <cname>foo</cname>
   </clerk>
</emp>
 </emplist>
```

The output I want for first case (which i am getting is )

```
id,1
name,foo
```

but for second I want

```
id, 1
name, foo
cid, 1
cname,foo
```

How do i flatten this out.
Thanks

Current code:

```
public class XMLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {

        //String xmlString = "<employee >\n <firstname xml:space=\"preserve\" >John</firstname>\n <lastname>Watson</lastname>\n <age>30</age>\n <email>johnwatson@sh.com</email>\n</employee>";
        String xmlString = "<employee>\n" + 
                "       <personal><id>2D61EC47-0F56-5A33-6057-54DB0ABBDBF0</id>\n" + 
                "       <name>Lareina</name>\n" + 
                "       <age>50</age>\n" + 
                "       </personal><contact><dept>Fusce</dept>\n" + 
                "       <manager>B55E6DA8-76BD-A3C8-2DDF-686CB9A0BB76</manager></contact>\n" + 
                "   </employee>";
        System.out.println(xmlString);


        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Reader in = new StringReader(xmlString);

        Document doc = builder.build(in);
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        List children = root.getChildren();
        //System.out.println(children);
        String value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {

                Element dataNode = (Element) children.get(i);
               // Element dataNode = (Element) dataNodes.get(j);
                value += ", " +dataNode.getText().trim();
                System.out.println(dataNode.getName() + " : " + dataNode.getText());

                //context.write(new Text(rowKey.toString()), new Text(node.getName().trim() + " " + node.getText().trim()));

            }
        //System.out.println(in);



    }
}
```

Comment: The second XML doesn't seems like valid XML. Don't you need a root element ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre: Sorry about that

Comment: It is still not valid. Look at the second <emplist> which should be </emplist>. Your expected output is inconsistent. Do you want to have a blank after the comma or not?

Comment: @MatthiasHerlitzius: Now is it valid??

Comment: Looks better now. What about proper indentation and my question concerning the expected output? Is it working now? Do you get any error messages? What are you doing to "flatten this out"? And what output do you currently get for the second XML?

Comment: Can you post source code that works with the first input?

Comment: Well, skipping some whitespace (String.trim() somewhere) shouldn't be a big issue. Also why create another XML parser? There are infinite amounts of XML parsers out theere already...

Comment: @SamiKorhonen: current implementation attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple implementation based on StAX instead of DOM. But you can easily convert it to DOM if you want (you will need to use recursion though).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;


public class FlattenXmlExample
{
  private static XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException
  {

    String xmlRecord =
        "<emplist>\n" +
        "<emp>\n" +
        "   <manager>\n" +
        "   <id>1</id>\n" +
        "   <name>foo</name>\n" +
        "   </manager>\n" +
        "</emp>\n" +
        "<emp>\n" +
        "   <clerk>\n" +
        "   <cid>1</cid>\n" +
        "   <cname>foo</cname>\n" +
        "   </clerk>\n" +
        "</emp>\n" +
        " </emplist>";

    String flatXmlRecord = flattenXmlRecord(xmlRecord);

    System.out.print(flatXmlRecord);
  }

  private static String flattenXmlRecord(final String xmlRecord) throws XMLStreamException
  {
    StringBuilder flatXmlRecord = new StringBuilder();

    XMLEventReader eventReader = inFactory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xmlRecord));

    while (eventReader.hasNext())
    {
      XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

      if (event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT )
      {
        String elementName = event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();


        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
        if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.CHARACTERS)
        {
          if(!event.asCharacters().getData().trim().isEmpty())
          {
            flatXmlRecord.append(elementName + ", " + event.asCharacters().getData() + "\n");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return flatXmlRecord.toString();
  }
}
```

Input:

```
<emplist>
<emp>
   <manager>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>foo</name>
   </manager>
</emp>
<emp>
   <clerk>
   <cid>1</cid>
   <cname>foo</cname>
   </clerk>
</emp>
 </emplist>
```

Output:

```
id, 1
name, foo
cid, 1
cname, foo
```